# Proper way to run Rider without Missing Templates

Tags: sudo, administration

I'm using Ubuntu x64 18.04 and Jetbrains Rider IDE 2019.1.3

If i download rider with snap or download & extract tar.gz file; I can run rider with clicking app icon on Ubuntu's launcher / unity.
It opens but rider's project templates(console app, webapi, xunit test app etc) are missing. But if I run rider with sudo like "sudo ./rider.sh" project templates are showing correctly.

So what is the proper way to install and run rider? Is launching rider with sudo a bad thing for security? Do I need to give some kind of chmod or admin rights to rider.sh? All I need is install and run rider with unity click - and it should work without errors like missing project templates or debug dll needs execution rights etc.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with temporary tiny-hack-solution like this;

I created a desktop shortcut with sudo bash commands in it. When I click it a terminal asks sudo password. If I enter it correctly, then I can launch rider, update rider etc. But it's a bad way to do it. ( If I update toolbox, what to do ? etc. )

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=run toolbox
Comment=runs toolbox
Exec=bash -c 'cd /opt/jetbrains-toolbox-1.15.5605 && sudo ./jetbrains-toolbox; bash'
Terminal=true
Type=Application

Name[en_US]=runtoolbox.desktop
```

Is there anyway to work properly with Jetbrains's Rider in Ubuntu ?